# Omitting explicit forall yields ambiguous type error

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I've run into a situation where a function fails to type-check unless I explicitly add a forall to the beginning of its type signature.

The function in question is:

```
test :: (Typeable a) => a -> a
test x 
    | typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: a) = x
    | otherwise = x
```

GHC gives the following warnings on the above:

```
  Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
  (Typeable a0) arising from a use of `typeOf'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the first argument of `(==)', namely `typeOf (undefined :: a)'
In the expression:
  typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: a)
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `test':
  typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: a)

Ambiguous type variable `a1' in the constraint:
  (Typeable a1) arising from a use of `typeOf'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `typeOf (undefined :: a)'
In the expression:
  typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: a)
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `test':
  typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: a)
```

So it's failing to unify the two types of the undefined values.  However if I add a forall a to the front:

```
test :: forall a. (Typeable a) => a -> a
test x 
    | typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: a) = x
    | otherwise = x
```

It compiles fine.  This is in GHC 7.4.2 using

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving, DeriveDataTypeable,
ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances,
Rank2Types #-}
```

I was under the impression that omitting "forall" in a type signature was equivalent to implicitly appending foralls to the beginning over all relevant type variables (as suggested in the GHC docs: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html).  Why does the first code fragment not type-check, while the second does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ScopedTypeVariables` extension adds semantic value to top-level `forall` quantifiers. It is what provides the scoping for the type variable over the body of the binding.

Without that `forall`, the type variable `a` on line 3 is a different type variable than the `a` on line 1. The error message indicates this by labeling them `a0` and `a1`. Without those being the same type, the type on line 3 is ambiguous, because it is completely unconstrained.

Comment: ref: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#decl-type-sigs

Comment: Thanks both of you, this makes sense.  I was confused because thanks to `ScopedTypeVariables` I'd been using similar constructs inside of class declarations without trouble; that documentation explains that this is because class declarations bring type variables into scope just like `forall` does in this case.